# Custom PS1: usual PS1 for all directories excluding single directory with subdirectories

Tags: bash, directory, prompt, ps1

Consider fixed absolute path to some directory with arbitrary subdirectories:

```
/full/path/to/fixed/directory
/full/path/to/fixed/directory/first_subdirectory
/full/path/to/fixed/directory/first_subdirectory/second_subdirectory
```

and arbitrary other directory that **is not** subdirectory of foregoing `directory`: `/other/path`

I want see the following in the terminal:

```
user@host: .../directory$ 
user@host: .../directory/first_subdirectory
user@host: .../directory/first_subdirectory/second_subdirectory
user@host: /other/path$
```

where the last line is a typical case but other lines are instead of

```
user@host: /full/path/to/fixed/directory$ 
user@host: /full/path/to/fixed/directory/first_subdirectory
user@host: /full/path/to/fixed/directory/first_subdirectory/second_subdirectory
```

How to implement it?

P.S. Paths can contain whitespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the special `PROMPT_COMMAND` var. For example:

```
[the-old-prompt] $ cat ps1
g_theSpecialDir=/tmp/im/the/magic/directory
g_pwd=

_prompt_cmd()
{
    if [[ $PWD/ == $g_theSpecialDir/* ]]; then
        g_pwd=.../${g_theSpecialDir##*/}${PWD#$g_theSpecialDir}
    else
        g_pwd=$PWD
    fi
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=_prompt_cmd
PS1='[\u@\h $g_pwd] $ '
[the-old-prompt] $ source ./ps1
[whjm@localhost /tmp] $ cd /tmp/im/the/magic/directory/
[whjm@localhost .../directory] $ cd dir1/
[whjm@localhost .../directory/dir1] $ cd dir2/
[whjm@localhost .../directory/dir1/dir2] $ cd /tmp/
[whjm@localhost /tmp] $
```

You can find the `PROMPT_COMMAND` var in the [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables). And this solution enables you to include anything you like in the prompt.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the function a little bit, and now it works for paths with whitespaces and show '~'' instead of home directory:

    _prompt_cmd()
    {
        if [[ "${PWD}/" == "${g_theSpecialDir}/"* ]]; then
            g_pwd=.../${g_theSpecialDir##*/}${PWD#"${g_theSpecialDir}"}
        elif [[ "${PWD}/" == "${HOME}/"* ]]; then
            g_pwd=~${PWD#"$HOME"}
        else
            g_pwd=${PWD}
        fi
    }